# can't get a container div around this slider

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

i've tried everything i can think of to get a slider inside a containing div, but it won't work.  does anybody have an idea?  this seems like it should be simple.

http://jsfiddle.net/thindery/LjjmC/

Comment: It's working fine for me? what doesn't work in the DEMO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/LjjmC/1/

The problem you're seeing is that the slider is floated, so the container div appears to have no contents in the flow.  By adding a "clear" div to the end of your container, the floated div appears inside the container div.

Comment: I'm always amazed how many people don't know about this but at the same time stunned we haven't found a better way. I HATE putting those extra divs all over my work. Anyone know any better ways? :/

Comment: [Read it HERE!](http://books.google.com/books?id=UgrUeIwsS60C&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=cederholm+.group+.clearfix&source=bl&ots=zeybfIhZb6&sig=sgx2GUNSok5plaJ4AnI3eL8jugc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_n7GT_H4BKjX0QHTqpDWBg&ved=0CFcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) - Dan Cedarholm wrote the best article in Handcrafted CSS. He purposes using the word 'group' rather than clearfix, which makes more sense to me. [Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) is a shortened explanation from http://css-tricks.com/